# About the native base sketch template

Tags: templates, native, radix

I'm quite new to react native development, and recently I saw the native base sketch template is quite a good starter for new app development, then I tried download the template, but my mac said can't open the .sketch file, can anyone enlight me how to use this template? should I import to xcode to open? or need other ide? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To open the .sketch file, you need to install the Sketch app (available for Mac only): https://www.sketchapp.com.